# Java code PMD Complains about Cyclomatic Complexity , of 20

Tags: java, performance, pmd

When i ran PMD on my Java Code ,  one of the Error Message it is showing is 
"The class STWeb has a Cyclomatic Complexity , of 20 " .
Typically my java class is of this way

```
public class STWeb implements STWebService {

  public String getData(RequestData request)
  {
    validate(request);
  }

  public boolean validate(Data[] formdata)
  {
    if(formdata.length==1)
    //do this 
    else if(formdata.length==3)
    //do this 
    else if(formdata.length==4)
    //do this 
    else if(formdata.length>4)
    //do this 
    else if(formdata.length==2)
    {
      if(formdata[0].getName.equals("OIY"))
      {
      }
    / And many more if else here 
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see , as per my business requirements , i need to code the class 
with many if's and  if else so the reason the cyclocomplexity has ncreased , please tell me 
what is feasible approach  as per the standard for this ??

Comment: Try indenting your code so we can see what is going on

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cyclomatic Complexity measurements shouldn't be used for quality control, but rather as an indicator/warning for bad code. You should focus more on the code behind it rather than the value of the CC itself.

Although you can reduce the complexity of the `validate` method by splitting it into smaller methods through refactoring, the class as a whole will still have the same CC.

As long as the code is **readable** and makes sense to the next person that has to look at it, then having a higher CC shouldn't matter so much.

Comment: It worked for me also, I extracted the code into multiple method calls using refactoring and it resolved this issue

Answer (score 2):

It helps if you have something like this:

```
if (a) {
   return true;
} else if (b) {
   return true;
} else if (c) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

then, you replace it with this:

```
return a || b || c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, that sometimes it's possible to resolve such problems with object- or structure-building. You could declare a "Wrapper-Class" for your data that is supposed to be returned. But there are always cases when you can't apply this without bloating the code with tons of objects, which in return also results in unreadable code ^^"

**EDIT**: this SO-post is a [[nice example with ENUMS]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509370/4958869)

Answer (score 0):

Cyclomatic complexity seems to indicate the amount of code paths that exist. So if your requirements say you must use many ifs and if elses, then you can ignore that message.

Answer (score 0):

If this is mandatory - yes this happens despite it's futil - you can often reduce the class cyclomatic complexity by introducing base classes and move distribute the functions into the base classes until the per class cyclomatic complexity is ok.

Or simpler: add // NOPMD to your class:

```
public class VeryComplexStuff { // NOPMD
    ...
```